# Для чего нужен throw new NotImplementedException()

Tags: c#, .net, visual-basic

Не могу понять до конца, для чего используют конструкции вида `throw new NotImplementedException()`, и чем `throw`, например в `try-catch`, отличается от `throw new`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

В .NET есть несколько "системных" исключений, которые существуют, чтобы сообщить о причине отсутствия метода, но которые не надо ловить:

- `NotImplementedException` — метод не реализован, но *будет реализован в будущем*. Вариация на тему комментария TODO, которая приводит к падению при выполнении.
- `NotSupportedException` — метод не реализован и *никогда не будет реализован*. Используется, если базовый класс или реализуемый интерфейс имеют широкий API, и от потомков не предполагается реализация всех методов (например, потому что какая-то возможность не поддерживается).

По умолчанию при реализации интерфейса IDE генерирует методы с `throw new NotImplementedException()`, предполагая, что вы реализуете их. Если вы не собираетесь этого делать (например, ваша коллекция релизует `IList<>`, но не поддерживает запись), то следует заменить этот код на `throw new NotSupportedException("Foo is not supported due to...")` с сообщением о причине отсутствия реализации (например, в случае коллекци только для чтения сообщение может быть "Коллекция только для чтения не может быть изменена.").

Если вы хотите проверить код в работе, и `throw new NIE` вам мешает, то можно заменить код на заглушку, например, `return null; // TODO Implement Foo() method`.

Comment: Круто, этим обычно пренебрегают, а зря.

Comment: @VladD: в Java есть такие же.

Answer (score 26):

> Не могу понять до конца для чего используют конструкции вида throw new NotImplementedException()

Довольно часто необходимо переключиться на совершенно иной кусок кода, а какой-нибудь

```
// todo
return null;
```

благополучно забудется и заставит сначала дебажить, и только потом вспоминать, что код-то на самом деле не был дописан. Другими словами, это хороший способен маякнуть о незаконченном компоненте.

> чем throw например в try-catch отличается от throw new

`throw` может быть использовано только в `catch` блоке, `throw new` -- практически в любом месте кода.

`throw` выбрасывает *оригинальное* исключение. Эта конструкция полезна, когда вам при обработке исключения нужно произвести какие-то действия, например, залогировать исключение, а затем пробросить его дальше:

```
catch (MyException e)
{
    logger.Log(e);
    throw;
}
```

`throw new` выбрасывает *новый экземпляр* исключения. Часто эта конструкция используется для того, чтобы обернуть низкоуровневое исключение (например, `SqlException`) в более собственное высокоуровневое исключение (например, `UserNotFoundException`). Важный момент: информация об оригинальном исключении теряется! При отладке главным образом нас интересует стектрейс, поэтому важно всегда включать оригинальное исключение в качестве `InnerException`:

```
catch (SqlException e)
{
    throw new UserNotFoundException("Cannot find user", e);
}
```

Comment: Почему тогда если я реализую некоторый интерфейс в классе и в некоторых методах, которые мне не нужны оставляю данную конструкцию все работает без исключений?

Comment: "Ничем" -- неправда. `throw new` теряет оригинальный стектрейс.

Comment: @andreycha поправьте, пожалуйста, мой ответ.

Comment: @e1s эм, а вы их вызываете?

Comment: @Etki не совсем вас понял, использовать данные конструкции в "конечной" версии продукта нельзя?

Comment: @e1s: Ну, если вы на все сто уверены, что не реализованный метод никогда не будет вызван, то по идее можно. Например, такое часто встречается при имплементации `IValueConverter`'ов. (Хотя, возможно, это означает архитектурную проблему.)

Comment: @Etki обновил. Теперь могу с чистой совестью поставить плюс ответу :).

Comment: @VladD Для таких случаев есть исключение `NotSupportedException` — оно означает "метод не реализован и **никогда не будет реализован**". И это не архитектурная проблема. Например, в `Stream` такие методы встречаются налево и направо, и мелкомягкие считают, что лучше иметь единый интерфейс с проверками а-ля `IsFooSupported`, чем иерархию из 10 интерфейсов, которые приведут к бесконечным кастам и чрезмерной сложности. Та же философия с коллекциями.

Comment: @Discord: По сути, вы правы, да. Пойду подправлю код. Напишете отдельным ответом?

Comment: @VladD Не уверен, что к месту, но вот: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/451609

Comment: @andreycha спасибо

Answer (score 13):

**throw** предложение без выражения может быть использовано только в **catch** блоке. В этом случае оно переадресует текущее исключение далее за пределы данного `catch` блока.

Рассмотрите пример.

```
try
{
    //...

    //  Дай-ка я выброшу исключение
    //  так как я еще не знаю, что делать в этой части программы
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
catch ( NotImplementedException )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "Просто проигнорируем это исключение до лучших времен" );
}
catch ( Exception )
{
   //  Увы, это не мое исключение. Переброшу его я далее
   //  Пусть другие с ним разбираются
   throw;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

`NotImplementedException` используется при создании "заглушек" методов. Когда метод описан, но не содержит реализации как таковой. Подробнее можно почитать на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.notimplementedexception(v=vs.110).aspx).